# Select sum with a group by inside a group by

Tags: mysql

With this example iformation table:

[image]

How can i output this information?

[image]

I'm trying this query, 
but it's just returning me the total number of 'PART' rows for each 'NAMES'.

```
SELECT
    NAMES
  , SUM(PART = "F001") AS SUM_F001
  , SUM(PART = "F002") AS SUM_F002
  , SUM(PART = "F003") AS SUM_F003
FROM
  MY_TABLE
GROUP BY NAMES ASC
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close with your current query. 
But you need to use the query below to correctly pivot.

```
SELECT 
    NAMES
  , MAX(CASE WHEN PART = 'F001' THEN QTY ELSE 0 END) AS F001
  , MAX(CASE WHEN PART = 'F002' THEN QTY ELSE 0 END) AS F002
  , MAX(CASE WHEN PART = 'F003' THEN QTY ELSE 0 END) AS F003
  , SUM(QTY) AS alias
FROM 
 FROM
  MY_TABLE
GROUP BY
  NAMES # Don't use ASC OR DESC on GROUP BY because it's deprecated
ORDER BY
 NAMES ASC
```

Comment: It's probably safer to use SUM rather than MAX in case a user has multiple entries in the table with the same PART number. That seems to be what the OP is implying in his comment about his query.

Comment: You might be right about that @Nick iám used to writting pivot queries with `MAX(..)`. Because`MAX(..)` works correctly on all datatypes where SUM doesn't.. Besides the output off this query will also match this expected output.

Comment: @Raymond it all works, thank you very much . 
And thanks for the tip of 'ASC OR DES' .

Answer (score 0):

U can use the query as follows

```
SELECT NAMES , SUM(CASE WHEN PART = 'F001' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F001 , SUM(CASE WHEN PART = 'F002' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F002 , SUM(CASE WHEN PART = 'F003' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F003 , SUM(QTY) AS alias FROM FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY NAMES ORDER BY NAMES ASC
```